# What is the limit in calldata parameters in EVM?

Tags: solidity, evm, calldata

Is it possible to send array of 2^18 or 262144 numbers of elements as a calldata? How much gas would that cost? Does it even make sense to have that large array in terms of gas cost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array of 2^18 bytes32 values would require approximately 5 million gas to send as calldata.

In an ideal scenario....no, but I'm not here to define requirements or ask for use cases. I wouldn't recommend it purely based on gas costs.

More practical to store the data in a separate contract or on a decentralized storage platform such as IPFS and access it as needed.